# How to set constraints on generic types in Java?

Tags: java, generics, constraints

I have a generic class:

```
public class ListObject<T>
{
    // fields
    protected T _Value = null;
      // ..
}
```

Now I want to do something like the following:

```
ListObject<MyClass> foo = new ListObject<MyClass>();
ListObject<MyClass> foo2 = new ListObject<MyClass>();
foo.compareTo(foo2);
```

**Question:**

How can I define the `compareTo()` method with resprect to the generic `T`?

I guess I have to somehow implement a constraint on the generic `T`, to tell that `T` implements a specific interface (maybe `Comparable`, if that one exists).

Can anyone provide me with a small code sample?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Read also the discussion here: [Generics and sorting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071929/generics-and-sorting-in-java/2071969#2071969)

Short answer, the best you can get is:

```
class ListObject<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    ...
}
```

But there is also reason to just use:

```
class ListObject<T extends Comparable> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll stick to ListObject<T extends Comparable> for the moment.

Comment: Also check the related thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064169/what-does-this-class-declaration-mean-in-java/2072820, which discusses the need for wildcard of form:<? super T>

Answer (score 5):

This depends on exactly what you want the compareTo method to do.  Simply defining the compareTo method to take other `ListObject<T>` values is done by the following

```
public class ListObject<T> {
  public int compareTo(ListObject<T> other) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However if you want to actually call methods on that parameter you'll need to add some constraints to give more information about the `T` value like so

```
class ListObject<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `public class ListObject<T extends U>`. Only `T`s which implement `U` (or derive from `U`) will be allowable substitutions.

Comment: Gives me a compiler error.
Even with such a simple TestClass:

public class ConstraintTest<T implements Comparable> { }

Syntax error on token "implements",, expected

What am I missing?

Comment: @citronas: It's actually `extends` even for interfaces. Do note that if you use a base class with the `extends` attribute, you can actually add the base class directly to the generified object anymore, that's the biggest *(and worst)* side effect of the generics extension.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class ListObject<T implements Comparable> {...}
```

Comment: -1 Voted down because Comparable without the type parameter is a raw type which u shouldn't use with Java 1.5+